# shell script looping in folder structure and using awk to print specific path

Tags: bash, shell, awk

i'm using the following script to loop into directory based on year / month / date and get full path of the file there then echo url for that file

```
dir_proc=/var/data/2017
for month_day in {01..12}/{01..31}; do
    [[ -e $dir_proc/${month_day} ]] || continue
    for file in "$dir_proc/${month_day}/"*; do
        [[ -e $file ]] || continue
    echo "http://msite.com/${file}"
    done
done
```

exmaple of my current  output

```
http://msite.com/var/data/2017/01/10/file.jpg
```

i'm trying to use awk to remove the file system path for the url when i echo the output , the url should be like

```
http://msite.com/data/2017/01/10/file.jpg
```

any tips to adjust

Comment: You basically want `http://msite.com/var/data/2017/01/10/file.jpg` to be `http://msite.com/data/2017/01/10/file.jpg` ? without `var`?

Comment: Just use: `echo "http://msite.com/${file#/var}"`

Comment: thats clean and neat way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` method:

```
$ link="http://msite.com/var/data/2017/01/10/file.jpg"
$ echo "$link" | awk '{gsub("/var/","/")}1'
http://msite.com/data/2017/01/10/file.jpg
```

or `sed` method:

```
echo "$link" | sed 's#/var/#/#g'
http://msite.com/data/2017/01/10/file.jpg
```

Comment: OP has yet to clarify what needs to be changed, but assuming `/var/` need to removed, it can be done with parameter expansion easily without needing external tool like awk/sed...

Comment: when assigning variables, use single quotes unless double is needed, that way you avoid interpretation on `$`, `!` etc... when value is needed, use double quotes.. `a='asd     aesd'` (not able to show in comment, insert multiple spaces between the two words) and see the difference between `echo "$a"` and `echo $a`

Comment: Yes, you're right, just offer an alternative method.

Comment: coming to suggested solutions... for `awk` one, can use string instead of regex and `$0` is default.. so simplified to `awk '{gsub("/var/","/")}1'`... for `sed` one, just use different delimiter and avoid unnecessary escapes.. `sed 's#/var/#/#g'`